# What signature schemes allow for a space efficient multisig? Any that also allow others to easily add to an existing signature?

Tags: signature, multi-signature

For instance, Is there a scheme where 100 people could produce a signature that is only as long as one signature?

Is there one like this that can be done where each person can merely modify an existing signature to add theirs to an existing group signature without the group's cooperation?

Comment: Have you looked at pairing based multi signature schemes? In particular the one proposed by Boneh [Dan Boneh - Short Signatures based on Weil Pairings](https://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2001/22480516.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!